# Singular fit exception with rlm regression function

Tags: regression

Has anyone used the rlm regression function.   I am using a factor variable as part of this regression.  If the number of occurrences of any factor is 0 or 1 it complains with the error that

'x' is singular: singular fits are not implemented in 'rlm'

The droplevels function removes 0 occurrence factors, is there a way to eliminate ones that have occurrence of 1.